# getting get method when running post method

Tags: json, django, authentication, django-urls, django-class-based-views

I created class based view where In get method I am calling html page activate.html. and created post method where I posting some json data. I want to redirect same page and want to post data.

**When I am running activate.html page I get it but when I click on button for activate user Its printing same which I print in get method**

views.py

```
class ActivationView(View):
     def get (self, request, uid, token):
            print('get called in activate_user')
            return render(request, 'activate.html')
    
        def post(self, request, uid, token):
            print('UID : ', uid)
            print('Token : ', token)
            payload = json.dumps({'uid': uid, 'token': token})
            print("payload : " , payload)
            protocol = 'https://' if request.is_secure() else 'http://'
            web_url = protocol + request.get_host()
            djoser_url = getattr(settings, 'DJOSER.ACTIVATION_URL')
            post_url = web_url + djoser_url
            print('post_url : ' + post_url)
            response = request.post(post_url, data = payload)
            return HttpResponse(response.text)
```

I want to print uid and token in json format when I click on post button from html.

activate.html

```
<form action="" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <td input type="submit"><a href="" target="_blank" >Click Here For Activate Account</a></td>
 </form>
```

Comment: Well, you have an anchor tag (`a`) in there, obviously it will make a get request...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your form

```
<form action="" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <td ><button type="submit">Click Here For Activate Account</button></td>
</form>
```

this will works.